# Flow does not report the correct type for a variable without @flow

Tags: flowtype

I have a file with the following three lines.

```
//
var g1 = navigator.geolocation;
g1.getCurrentPosition(position => {}, () => {});
```

Flow reports the type of g1 as: "2:5-6: any" when I ran dump-types command. When I add @flow directive into the file as the following:

```
//@flow
var g1 = navigator.geolocation;
g1.getCurrentPosition(position => {}, () => {});
```

It correctly reports 2:5-6: Geolocation.

My question is how I can make Flow to perform the more precise type inference as if "@flow" was in files even if I cannot modify them.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? I ask, because writing a library definition (a-la flow-typed) might get you what you're looking for. (Otherwise I'm unsure of how to do this)

Comment: I want to get types of variables for another analysis. I've already added flow-typed definitions, and that's the reason why it reports Geolocation correctly when the @flow is added to the file.

Comment: I honestly don't quite understand what you're going for here. Do you want to throw up an MVP/repro-repo on github or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can set [all to true in .flowconfig [options] section](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-all-boolean):

```
[options]
all=true
```

> Set this to `true` to check **all** files, not just those with `@flow`.
>   The default value for `all` is `false`.